# iOS (iPad) parent view unloaded on memory warning

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory, memory-management

Here's the situation. I have a MainControlle which opens a modal XController. When memory warning is received (when XController is displayed) MainController is unloaded (viewDidUnload is called) and you can not go back from XController to MainController.

What could be the problem? How to fix that?

UPDATE:

Is it OK if I just comment a super method (so the OS will be forced to close other programs first before destroying this view) and set variables to nil only in dealloc?

```
(void)viewDidUnload
{ 
  // [super viewDidUnload]
}
```

Comment: Ideally you should be able yo reconstruct your MainController with viewDidLoad so it gets reloaded when you ask for it even if it got dumped for a memory warning.

Comment: @Dancreek: XController has a button calling dismissModalViewControllerAnimated. How would you reconstruct a parent?

Comment: My tests are saying that you can comment out super method and you move all releasing to dealloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... just comment everything out as I explained and it works.